# How to join a polymorphic table with its child tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am sorry about not being able to articulate the title of the question or the description of this question better. However, I will give the schema, sample data and expected result. Please help me write a query for such a use case.

**Schema of restaurants**

```
id
name
item_type
item_id
```

**Schema of foods**

```
id 
name
```

**Schema of food_items**

```
id 
name
food_id
```

*Sample data in restaurants*

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      id             |     name         |      item_type      |     item_id      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       1             | Apple Crushers   |      food_items     |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       2             |     Retro Cafe   |      foods          |         2        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       3             | Fruit Mania      |      foods          |         1        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       4             | Meat and Eat     |      NULL           |        NULL      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

*Sample data in foods:*

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      id             |     Name         |  
|---------------------|------------------|
|       1             |     Fruits       |     
|---------------------|------------------|
|       2             |     Chocolates   | 
|---------------------|------------------|
```

*Sample data in food_items*

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      id             |     Name         |      food_id        | 
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|       1             |     Apple        |        1            | 
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|       2             |     Mango        |        1            | 
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

I need to write a query such that I get this as my result.

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|      r_id           |     r_name       |      food_id        |     food_name    |    food_item_id     | food_item_name   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       1             | Apple Crushers   |      1              |         Fruit    |        1            |  Apple           |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       2             |     Retro Cafe   |      2              |      Chocolates  |        NULL         |     NULL         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       3             | Fruit Mania      |      1              |       Fruit      |      NULL           |    NULL          |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
|       4             | Meat and Eat     |      NULL           |        NULL      |         NULL        |       NULL       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|------------------|
```

p.s: It will also be very helpful if someone could come up with an appropriate title and description for this problem. I am lost for words to describe this.

Comment: I have removed the conflicting RDBMS tags. Please tag properly and *only* tag the RDBMS you are actually using.

Comment: Okay but I thought the same will probably work for MySQL as well.

Comment: Tagging multiple RDBMS (3 in your case, MySQL, SQL Server and PostgreSQL) just confuses those you're asking for help from and we don't know what dialect you need. As a result your question is likely to get less attention (or negative attention). Only tag the RDBMS you are asking about.

Comment: The column names are a tad confusing. `restaurant.item_type` tells us the table a `restaurants.item_id` refers to, I suppose? So, `'Apple Crushers'` is linked to `'Mango'`, `'Retro Cafe'` to `'Chocolates'`, and `'Fruit Mania'` to `'Fruits'` (which itself is linked to `'Mango'` and `'Apple'`)? But your result shows different. Please explain.

Comment: Sorry `Apple Crushers` is supposed to be linked to `Apple` only I have updated the sample data.
Since fruit mania is liked to Fruit, we are not displaying any of the subsets.

Comment: a restaurant can have only one item_type?

Comment: Yes it can have only one item_type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the food table twice and use `COALESCE`:

```
select
  r.id,
  r.name,
  coalesce(f.id, fif.id) as food_id,
  coalesce(f.name, fif.name) as food_name,
  fi.id as food_item_id,
  fi.name as food_item_name
from restaurants r
left join foods f on f.id = r.item_id and r.item_type = 'foods'
left join food_items fi on fi.id = r.item_id and r.item_type = 'food_items'
left join foods fif on fif.id = fi.food_id
order by r.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select r.id, r.name, foods.id, foods.name, food_items.id, food_items.name from restaurents as r 
left join food_items on r.item_type = 'food_items' and r.item_id = food_items.id
left join foods on (r.item_type = 'foods' and r.item_id = foods.id) or (r.item_type = 'foods' and r.item_id = food_items.food_id)
```

This might be having some syntax issues related to table names, but it should work.

Comment: Results are not coming properly.
As in food_item is getting populated, but the corresponding food is not getting populated. @lokanadham100

Answer (score 0):

For your database, I would suggest another data model based on compound keys. This would guarantee data consistency and makes queries a tad simpler:

```
food_group
(
  food_group_no  integer       not null,
  name           varchar(100)  not null,
  primary key (food_group_no)
);

food
(
  food_group_no  integer       not null,
  food_no        integer       not null,
  name           varchar(100)  not null,
  primary key (food_group_no, food_no)
);

restaurant
(
  restaurant_no  integer       not null,
  name           varchar(100)  not null,
  food_group_no  integer       not null,
  food_no        integer       null,
  primary key (restaurant_id),
  foreign key (food_group_no) references food_group(food_group_no),
  foreign key (food_group_no, food_no) references food(food_group_no, food_no)
);
```

The query:

```
select
  r.restaurant_no,
  r.name as restaurant_name,
  fg.food_group_no,
  fg.name as food_group_name,
  f.food_id,
  f.name as food_name
from restaurants r
join food_group fg on fg.id = r.food_group_no
left join food f on f.food_group_no = r.food_group_no and f.food_no = r.food_no
order by r.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for a much detailed answer. Our system is a complex system, I have changed the table names and many details, will look into your answer and do what is best for our needs. Thanks a lot.